# HashMap is returning wrong value for Integer key

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a HashMap the following HashMap

`private Map<Integer, List<CustomClass>> map = new HashMap<>();`

I am trying to add a new entry in HashMap against an Integer key and if the key exists then I want to fetch the corresponding list and add new item in it. Code is given below.

```
        if (this.map.containsKey(//Integer Key)) {
            this.map.get(//Integer Key).add(//New List Item);
        } else {
            List<CustomClass> customClass = new ArrayList<>();
            customClass.add(new CustomClass());
            this.map.put(//Integer Key, customClass);
        }
```

The real problem lies in the part where a key already exists and I try to use HashMap get function

`this.map.get(//Integer Key).add(//New List Item);`

It is not giving null is if couldn't find the value for Integer key but it gives wrong ArrayList quite often. Now I know HashMap works with equals and hashCode so I tried to Override these functions and used them instead of Integery Key.

```
public class CustomHashMapIntegerKey {

    private Integer key = 0;

    public void setKey(Integer key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public Integer getKey() {
        return this.key;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return this.key.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) return true;
        if (null == obj) return false;
        if (this.getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;
        final CustomHashMapIntegerKey customHashMapIntegerKey = (CustomHashMapIntegerKey) obj;
        if (null == this.key && null != customHashMapIntegerKey.getKey()) return false;
        if (null != this.key) {
            if (!this.key.equals(customHashMapIntegerKey.getKey())) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

and changed my map to use this new class for key instead of Integer, but I am still stuck on the same problem where HashMap is giving wrong value. A bit detailed snipped is available at this link https://gist.github.com/MAnfal/dc581234ce597a8ff062

Comment: If there was a bug in HashMap, you would have been able to find out about it in a Google search (and it would have been fixed already). An java.lang.Integer is also something that is extremely unlikely to have bugs. The most likely cause of your problem is that you are supplying the wrong integer to the `Map.get()` method.

Comment: I double checked using debugger including instanceof, value, boolean value of my key vs the obtained from hashmap. I am not saying that its java's fault but somehow everything i tried is failing to give me appropriate result.

Comment: The hashing depends on the key, and if it’s an integer, then it’s very unlikely to  “give [you a] wrong ArrayList”. Recheck your code.

Comment: if possible, share your entire code

Comment: `Integer` class already implements `equals` and `hashcode` methods so no need to have `CustomHashMapIntegerKey`. It should work unless application logic is doing something wrong. Could be a multi-threading issue. Are there multiple threads that trying to read and write into HashMap. If so, consider using `synchronized Map` or better a `ConcurrentHashMap`

Comment: original code is a bit long, I am just pasting the part where the problem is occuring. 
https://gist.github.com/MAnfal/dc581234ce597a8ff062

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu no the map is accessible to a single thread if it was multithreaded access i would've definitely used synchronized.

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu that was my thought as well that Integer should have its own implementation of hashCode and equals so no need to provide one but when it didnt work out then i moved to my own class.

Comment: Add your code link in question itself for better visibility.

Comment: I'm not sure it's your problem and you definitely don't need your own custom class, but your equals method is bugged. If ``this.key==null` it returns true.

Answer (score 2):

The `HashMap` relies in part on `equals` and `hashCode` to do its work, but it is a bit more complicated. Take a look at [this article](http://javahungry.blogspot.com/2013/08/hashing-how-hash-map-works-in-java-or.html) for an in depth explanation.

For your purose (Map with a list as its value), I suggest the use of [`Multimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) from Google's Guava library:

```
ListMultimap<Integer, String> multimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
multimap.put(4, "Is the first digit of '4'");
multimap.put(4, "Is the first digit of '42'");
multimap.put(4, "Is the first digit of '4711'");
multimap.put(1, "Is the first digit of '13'");

Collection<String> values = multimap.get(4);
```

The `Collection` `values` will contain the three elments that you added under the key `4`.

Comment: I know HashMap uses hashCode and equals, and thanks for the suggestion but I will hold of on using Guava for now, I dont wanna use entire library for a single function which I can achieve through core java.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt the values stored in your Map. With the details you have provided, your issue could happen only in one case, where you must be adding the same Object in different lists and store with different keys in the HashMap. Log your Map contents, and print the objects hash codes, that might help you

Comment: I have checked the log I am adding different objects in the same list the only common these objects have with the map is the item id (passed as the key to the map). And for the purpose of combining items with same id in an array list i have used this data structure.

Comment: Can you share the code where this method is called ?

Comment: Say if the items has id as 3 and its stored in a list and put to the Map with the Key 3, the next time you get an Item with id 3 it should get the list where all the items have that same id. But what you see is a list with the items whose item id is something else. is my understanding correct ?

Comment: No I mean the code that calls the addToDepartmentItemMap method passing the departmentItemHolder and the departmentItemHolder class too, if possible

Comment: Am sorry am unable to help you... I looked at your code multiple times but I still doubt some where else the objects are messed up. As long as you are using the java.util.HashMap and use Integer as a key, It will never ever return a wrong list.

Comment: I'm also having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Check that the value you overgive to `map.get(value)` is exactly the type of the key of the map** - in my example below either int or Integer, but neither long, Long, byte, ... nor Byte.

I found this post, when I had a similar problem by e. g. calling  `getText(5);` the method returned `null`!
But no answer and comment helped me. But finally I saw the problem:

```
package ch.omwo.common.german.numbers;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class NumberConverter {

    public String getText(long number) { // with long it does not work, with int it works!
        
        HashMap<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>()
        {
            {
                    put(1, "eins"        );
                    put(2, "zwei"        );
                    put(3, "drei"        );
                    put(4, "vier"        );
                    put(5, "fünf"        );
                    put(6, "sechs"       );
                    put(7, "sieben"      );
                    put(8, "acht"        );
                    put(9, "neun"        );
                    put(10, "zehn"       );
            }
        };
        
        return map.get(number); // this is defined as: public V get(Object key)
    }
}
```

If I looked into the code - `Integer.hashCode(5)` and `Long.hashCode(5)` deliver the same hashcode for 5 -> 5.

```
public static int hashCode(int value) {
       return value;
}

public static int hashCode(long value) {
    return (int)(value ^ (value >>> 32));
}
```

Because `map.get(Object key)` expects an Object, the long value 5 will be boxed into an Object of type **L**ong with value 5.
Inside the code the hash is right, but the next step is comparing the Integer key with  `==` to the Long object.
Here I am not sure, whether it will take reference comparision (that would fail anyway) or `equals`, where this code comes from Integer class:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Integer) {
        return value == ((Integer)obj).intValue();
    }
    return false;
}
```

The parameter `obj` is no instance of Integer (but Long) and therefore `equals` will return false and `map.get` finally `null`.

That was the reason of my "bug".

**In this case no implicit type conversion occurs! Only boxing.**